# Normalizer of $H_0 \times H_m$ in $S_{2n}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H_0 \subsetneq \dotso \subsetneq H_m$ be a chain of subgroups of $S_n$ (the symmetric group of $n$ elements) such that holds: $N(H_i) = H_{i+1}$ and $N(H_m) = H_m$. I want to prove that the normalizer of $H_i \times H_m \subset S_{2n}$ is actually $H_{i+1} \times H_m$. One inclusion is trivial, but I could not prove the other one.

I tried showing that $N(H_i \times H_m)$ is a subset of $S_n \times S_n$, after which the result is clear. It is enough to show that for any $\alpha \in N(H_i \times H_m)$ we have $\alpha(i) \in \{1,...,n\}$ for any $i \leq n$. Didnt see a way to do this, does anybody have a hint?

Comment: What makes you think that this is true?

Comment: Hmm I actually dont. It was just part of a more detailed exercise and I thought this was the way to prove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counterexample is $H_0 = \langle (1,2) \rangle < S_5$, $H_1=\langle (1,2),(3,4),(4,5) \rangle$.

Let $G = H_0 \times H_1 = \langle(1,2),(6,7),(8,9),(9,10) \rangle < S_{10}$.

Then $(1,6)(2,7) \in N_{S_{10}}(G)$.